# Open source javascript GUI component toolkit

Tags: javascript

Is there any open source javascript GUI component toolkit ?

Comment: You mean.. the ones which you use to show dialogs, buttons, sliders, etc without writing much code or CSS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on what you mean wih GUI component toolkit, but I would give a look at :`

- [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/)
- [Dojo](http://jqueryui.com/)
- [ExtJS](http://www.extjs.com/)
- [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/)
- [Scriptacolous](http://script.aculo.us/)
- [Cappucino](http://cappuccino.org/)
- [OpenLaszlo](http://www.openlaszlo.org/)

They span a wide area of capabilities and support. Maybe one of them fits your use cases.